# Android: how to unregister the ContentObserver and DataSetObserver of a CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, contentobserver

I found there is no interface in side CursorAdapter to unregister the ContentObserver and DataSetObserver it apply. 
I can only use Cursor.getCursor().close() to close the cursor but cannot unregister its observers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling CursorAdapter.changeCursor(null) will unregister all the observers and close the cursor.